# Sequelize subquery products and ratings

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a code. I want to get: list of products, order by amount,average rating, amount of ratings. As a result I get only ONE product -_-.

```
Product.findAll({
      offset,
      limit: 15,
      order: [["amount", "desc"]],
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Rating,
          attributes: [
            [
              sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "averageRating"
            ],
            [
              sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "amountOfRatings"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }).then(products => products));
```

If I delete:

```
include: [
            {
              model: models.Rating,
              attributes: [
                [
                  sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
                  "averageRating"
                ],
                [
                  sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
                  "amountOfRatings"
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
```

I get all of I need,without ratings.
url of full project: https://github.com/Deeathwiing/VSTU-LAB-SERVER-EXPRESS ;
Thank for answers;

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that sequelize does an `inner join` by default. You need an equivalent `left outer join` so that product rows are returned even if there are no asscociated ratings.

You can change the default behavior by specifying `required: false` on your include statement:

```
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Rating,
          required: false,
          attributes: [
            [
              sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "averageRating"
            ],
            [
              sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "amountOfRatings"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: sql query from sequelize: 
SELECT `product`.*, `ratings`.`id` AS `ratings.id`, avg(`ratingValue`) AS `ratings.averageRating`, count(`ratingValue`) AS `ratings.amountOfRatings` FROM (SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`price`, `product`.`title`, `product`.`amount`, `product`.`description`, `product`.`picture`, `product`.`createdAt`, `product`.`updatedAt` FROM `products` AS `product` ORDER BY `product`.`amount` DESC LIMIT 0, 15) AS `product` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` AS `ratings` ON `product`.`id` = `ratings`.`productId` ORDER BY `product`.`amount` DESC;

Comment: I was write query in sql and it is works:
use omvapeshop;
SELECT `products`.*, (Select avg(ratingValue) from ratings where productId = `products`.`id` ) as averageRating, 
(Select count(ratingValue) from ratings where productId = `products`.`id` ) as amountOfRatings
from products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ratings` ON `products`.`id` = `ratings`.`productId`
ORDER BY `products`.`amount` DESC
LIMIT 0, 15;

Comment: I hate sequelize

Comment: always takes a little tweaking, but main issue at the start is the left outer join to return products even if there are no ratings

Comment: Problem isnt in join, I'm shure

Comment: I was used 3 products with rating